# Specifying bounds on gradient color fill using ggplot2 on histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, gradient

I'm relatively new to R, so I apologize in advance if I made mistakes in the code or used incorrect terminology. I am attempting to create several histograms with a gradient color fill. I was easily able to do this using ggplot and the following is what I was able to get ([Multiple Histograms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qf42.png)). As can be seen in this figure, the scale remains consistent across all values.

Now, my goal is to recreate each of these histograms individually so that I can add a geom_label to the corner ([Single Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DpsB.png)), but the scale of the gradient fill is reset for each histogram to that specific data set. Does anyone know how I can keep the scale of the gradient fill in the single histogram figure consistent across all histograms I make (just like the multiple histograms figure)?

Thanks in advance

```html
mydata<-read_excel("DataBook.xlsx", sheet=3)

meanprice<-mean(mydata$surf, na.rm=TRUE)
sdprice<-sd(mydata$surf, na.rm=TRUE)

meantxt <- paste("Mean = $", format(round(meanprice, 2), nsmall=2), sep="")
sdtxt <- paste("Standard Deviation = $", format(round(sdprice, 2), nsmall=2), sep="")
fulltxt <- paste(meantxt, sdtxt, sep="\n")
limitx <- round_any(max(mydata$surf, na.rm=TRUE), 10, f=ceiling)
filename <- paste("Histogram_surf.png")

p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=surf)) + 
 geom_histogram(color="black", aes(fill=..count..))+ 
 scale_x_continuous(name = "Price ($/Unit)", breaks=seq(0, limitx, 50), limits=c(0,limitx), expand=c(0,0)) +
 scale_y_continuous(name = "Number of Awarded Bids", expand=c(0,0), breaks=seq(0, 250, 25), limits=c(0, 250))
p + theme_bw(base_size=16, base_family='Times New Roman')+ 
 ggtitle("HMA-Surface Course")+
 theme(plot.title=element_text(color="black", size=18, face="bold", hjust=0.5), axis.title = element_text(color="black", size=16, face="bold"), legend.position="none")+ 
 geom_label(x=Inf, y=Inf, aes(label = fulltxt), hjust=1, vjust=1, size=(18*(4/15)), family='Times New Roman')
ggsave(filename, dpi=300, height=4, width=5, units="in")
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the limits in a scale? `+ scale_fill_continuous(limits = c(0, 250))`, for example. The 250 is eyeballed from the example plot.

Comment: That worked perfect! Thank you so much. If you transfer it to an "answer" I'll upvote this.